# .Net 6 Blazor Wasm and IIS Express 10 gets Unable to configure HTTPS endpoint. No server certificate was specified

Tags: .net-core, blazor-webassembly, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022, iis-express-10

I get the above error when I create a new Blazor Wasm (configured for HTTPS) app.

I know there are several questions similar to this one, but after upgrading to .Net 6 from pre-release, I uninstalled several .Net runtimes and SDKs so I was left with:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>dotnet --list-runtimes
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.20 [C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.0 [C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.20 [C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.0 [C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.20 [C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 6.0.0 [C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
```

Afterwhich I started receiving the above error when running .net6 blazor wasm app in iis express 10 on Windows 11.

I've read many articles here and elsewhere and tried all combinations of deleting, adding, testing, and trusting the vs2022 certs in the Certs.mmc for both "Current User" and "Local Computer" using:

dotnet dev-certs https --clean
dotnet dev-certs https -t
dotnet dev-certs https --trust

I also manually went into the 4 areas in the 2 MMCs (User and Computer for both Personal and Trusted certs) and cleared them out, created, exported and imported them back, but nothing seemed to help. I've uninstalled and reinstalled IIS Express 10, repaired VS2022, and added back the .Net 5 and Core 3.1 runtimes.

Comment: What happens when you execute the app from the command line with `dotnet run`? You *don't* need IIS to run a web application on Windows. `dotnet dev-certs https` configure Kestrel to use the developer certificate but IIS requires its own configuration. After all, in a production server hosting multiple virtual directories each one will probably use a *different* certificate

Comment: I'm now showing no SDKs installed even tho I just reinstalled VS2022 with .net6 and SDK options checked. Microsoft really needs a reliable utility for cleaning up old SDKs and runtimes. I'll probably have to reinstall Windows 11.